# Migration from NEXUS to JFrog using script failed

Tags: github, migration, artifactory, nexus

I tried to use a new script for migrating data from NEXUS to JFrog https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Migrating+from+Sonatype+Nexus+Repository+Manager+to+Artifactory. The script failed with the error. I noticed that it tried to use github.com/jfrog/jfrog-nexus-migrator/ which does not exist on the github.

Is there a user who was successful with this type of migration? Do you think the script is valid?

> ```
>   Fetching the Nexus version
> ```
>
> panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>
> ```
>  goroutine 1 [running]: github.com/jfrog/jfrog-nexus-migrator/internal/appcommons.Nexus_version(0x7ffcec031edc,
> ```
>
> 0x16, 0x7ffcec031f00, 0x5, 0x7ffcec031f17, 0xf, 0x23, 0xd47cac,
> 0xc000143810, 0xc00000d710)
> /opt/nexus-migrator/internal/appcommons/url_endpoints.go:430 +0x18f github.com/jfrog/jfrog-nexus-migrator/commands.StartsetConfig(0xc000164ae0,
> 0x0, 0x0)
> /opt/nexus-migrator/commands/setConfig.go:124 +0x44c github.com/jfrog/jfrog-nexus-migrator/commands.GetsetConfigCommand.func1(0xc000164ae0,
> 0xc0000c1600, 0xc000065260)
> /opt/nexus-migrator/commands/setConfig.go:40 +0x2b github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-core/v2/plugins/components.getActionFunc.func1(0xc0000c1600,
> 0x101010100, 0xc0000c1600)
> /pkg/mod/github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-core/v2@v2.1.1/plugins/components/conversionlayer.go:162
> +0xe5 github.com/codegangsta/cli.HandleAction(0xc49020, 0xc000198440, 0xc0000c1600, 0xc000065300, 0x0)
> /pkg/mod/github.com/codegangsta/cli@v1.20.0/app.go:488 +0x45 github.com/codegangsta/cli.Command.Run(0xd48fde, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0,
> 0xc000198330, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0001b2900, ...)
> /pkg/mod/github.com/codegangsta/cli@v1.20.0/command.go:210 +0x9bb github.com/codegangsta/cli.(*App).Run(0xc00014e680, 0xc000030080, 0x8, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
> /pkg/mod/github.com/codegangsta/cli@v1.20.0/app.go:255 +0x768 github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-core/v2/plugins.PluginMain(0xd4bd5f, 0xe,
> 0xd68ba4, 0x32, 0xd47657, 0x6, 0xc000111c00, 0x6, 0x6)
> /pkg/mod/github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-core/v2@v2.1.1/plugins/pluginmain.go:65
> +0x205 main.main()
> /opt/nexus-migrator/main.go:10 +0xa5

Answer (score 0):

I can tell from experience that many people have been able to migrate using this tool, and for very large instances.

The migrator tool uses a Nexus script that is installed via API. I would suggest you check whether scripts are enabled on your Nexus instance. If they are I would verify that the nexus script is installed or not. You can do a "get scripts" nexus api and search for the migrator. If it's there and the tool is not running, you may want to delete so that the tool redeploys.

Lastly, I suggest run one step at a time instead of running "all" to understand better where it's failing.